# JavaMail SMTP Socket takes 1.5 min to Connect

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-mail

A web application (Tomcat6, Java6) on a cloud server (Linux, Debian Wheezy) is suddenly taking 1-2 minutes to connect to a remote SMTP to send out an email.

I've logged into the server and confirmed I can ping and telnet into the SMTP server without any issues. The problem seems to be happening only when Java attempts the connection.

```java
INFO  2015-01-12 16:17:58,872 [ajp-8009-10]
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "XXXXXXX", port XXX, isSSL false
INFO  2015-01-12 16:19:32,753 [ajp-8009-11] ......
220 XXXXXXXXX ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "XXXXXXXX", port: XXX
```

You can see that the connection attempt begins at 16:17:58 and the connection is finally made at 16:19:32 - almost 1.5 minutes later.

When I do the same from Telnet the response from the server is instant that's why it seems so strange that the app should take so long to connect. No other exceptions appear in the log files.

I have contacted the company running the SMTP server as well as the cloud hosting provider to see if they have any suggestions. Any insight or approach to find the source of the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Not possible. A TCP connection attempt will time out in significantly less than 90 seconds. There must be something else time-consuming happening in between.

Comment: The default timeouts for whatever reason are set to infinity by default when using the JavaMail API.

Comment: Please make a packet capture and publish it to cloudshark.org, to see where the real problem is.

Comment: As others have suggested, you probably need to dig into this in more detail to find out exactly where the delay is.  One thing that can caused unexpected delays is host name lookups.  Just for debugging, try adding the IP addresses for your mail server and your local machine to your machine's "hosts" file.  If that helps, you need to look into your name service configuration.

Comment: I was able to capture the packets to see what as happening. The connection is made in the first 3 packects (ACK, SYN ACK, ACK) but then the server waits 110 seconds before sending the greeting. I thought maybe they had added some rules in acl_connect? However when they finally got back to me it turns out that they are in the middle of implementing some sort of redirection to the nearest server based on where you are. This morning their hostname started to resolve to new IPs which seems to have fixed the problem. My best guess right now was that their old IP was cached either in Java or the OS.

Comment: I was also mistaken about the connection from Telnet. Telnet would connect right away but I only noticed later that the greeting came after a long delay. The connection on our dev computers was fine but I never thought to check to see if there is any difference in how the hosts were being resolved.